# how to combine two queries in larvel way

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

- `tb_user`
- `tb_addquestion`
- `tb_answer`

The following queries return *count of questions per user* (`query 1`) and *answers per user* (`query 2`). I need to combine the results to a single output.

How can I achieve this with the help of a single query?

##### Count of questions per user (query1)

```sql
SELECT tb_addquestion.userid,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM tb_addquestion
LEFT JOIN tb_user
    ON tb_user.userid = tb_addquestion.userid
GROUP BY tb_addquestion.userid
HAVING count > 0 AND
       count < 15
```

##### Answers per user (query2)

```sql
SELECT tb_answer.userid,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM tb_answer
LEFT JOIN tb_user
    ON tb_user.userid = tb_answer.userid
GROUP BY tb_answer.userid
HAVING count > 0 AND
       count < 15
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem on running 2 separate queries ? If you combine them, they will still run as 2 queries (if you can combine them).

Comment: @matiaslauriti Are you sure there's no difference (in terms of performance) between two separate queries (= two DB requests) and one combined query (= one DB request)?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner The DB performance would be the same or joining them in the same query, would be worst...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UNION`:

```sql
SELECT tb_addquestion.userid,
       COUNT(*) AS count,
       'questions' AS type
FROM tb_addquestion
LEFT JOIN tb_user
    ON tb_user.userid = tb_addquestion.userid
GROUP BY tb_addquestion.userid
HAVING count > 0 AND
       count < 15 

UNION

SELECT tb_answer.userid,
       COUNT(*) AS count,
       'answers' AS type
FROM tb_answer
LEFT JOIN tb_user
    ON tb_user.userid = tb_answer.userid
GROUP BY tb_answer.userid
HAVING count > 0 AND
       count < 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically we would perform the aggregations in separate subqueries, and then join the main table to each of those subqueries:

```sql
SELECT
    u.userid,
    COALESCE(aq.q_cnt, 0) AS q_cnt,
    COALESCE(a.a_cnt, 0) AS a_cnt
FROM tb_user u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS q_cnt
    FROM tb_addquestion
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING q_cnt > 0 AND q_cnt < 15
) aq
    ON aq.userid = u.userid
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS a_cnt
    FROM tb_answer
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING a_cnt > 0 AND a_cnt < 15
) a
    ON a.userid = u.userid
```